# I can be handy - What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Starts out from the last,
I work my way up if asked.
You will laugh if I'm slothful,
And cry if I'll not careful.
I can make your mouth shut,
followed by that furry nut!

What am I?

Comment: Is the title correct? "I can by handy"? Or should it be "I can *be* handy"?

Comment: @RodrigoSalgadoAtala typo, happnes to me eevry Firday

Comment: My English is not good, so which meaning should I understand for "furry nut", bro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are a...

> Zipper!

Starts out from the last,

> Begins with the letter 'Z'

I work my way up if asked.

> If you pull at a zipper, it goes up!

You will laugh if I'm slothful,

> People who leave their fly open are readily mocked!

And cry if I'll not careful.

> Ouch!

I can make your mouth shut,

> A 'zipper-mouth' is a common analogy for someone who is keeping schtum.

followed by that furry nut!

> ... self explanatory?

Comment: You got it!  However the last line is another hint; try and see if you can get it before I accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> Toothpaste

Explanation:

Starts out from the last,

> You start pushing the toothpaste out by pressing from the bottom...

I work my way up if you ask it.

> ...and then moving up as you use it.

You will laugh if I'm slothful,

> Maybe this alludes to toothpaste coming out slowly which is a convenience

And cry if I'll not careful.

> If it comes out all of a sudden, it can spill and go waste.

I can make your mouth shut,

> You shut your mouth to brush your teeth.

followed by that furry nut!

> This refers to the toothbrush.

Comment: Only if line 3 - 4 fit,  Not the answer but interesting thought!